# How to retrograde a note sequence in Finale?

Tags: finale

For instance, if I have written the C minor arpeggio from C2 to C6, how could I do to write the same note sequence but, in this time, starting from C6 to C2? Could this be done automatically, retrograding the already written note sequence?

This is a tool that I often miss, I don't know if it is possible to do it with Finale...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't personally own Finale, but I understand there is a "Canonic Utilities" tool that allows you to do such transformations.

According to [this site on Finale's page](https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2014Win/Content/Finale/Canonic_Utilities_Plug_in.htm), you can find it under **Plug-Ins** => **Scoring and Arranging** => **Canonic Utilities**. I admit that I don't fully know what you're looking for—exact inversion, or inversion within the C-minor arpeggio?—but these various inversion options should at least save you time in getting to where you want to get.

Also included are various transposition and retrograde options.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. When I said "to invert", I said it in the sense of reversing the order, making the last notes first and the first ones last.

Comment: @Quaerendo Excellent! In that sense, you may be more interested in the retrograde option than in the inversion option. Retrograde reverses the order, whereas inversion flips it upside down.

Comment: Great. I’m still using Finale, but I didn’t know this too.